# Derby seems to ignore port duplication

Tags: derby

I configured embedded mode in my application and allowed other clients to connect my embedded derby with network server mode.
(-Dderby.drda.startNetworkServer=true -Dderby.drda.portNumber=8233)

Before I run my application, I loaded other application with network-server mode derby. The problem is that the derby use same port, 8233 with my application.

And other clients having data-source indicates my application’s derby(embedded) put data, I couldn’t get the data in my application.

I was blocked for a long time solving this problem, 
Finally, I found that the data other clients put was in other derby on other application.

I think that…
When loading embedded derby in my application, derby have to know whether or not the port is using.
And If the port is using by other application, the error have to be appeared in the console. But it was not. Can you explain about?

Thanks you for your effort and time…

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the operating system allows two different processes to open network sockets and accept connections on the same port number depends on many different factors, including:

1. Which precise operating system is being used
2. The configuration parameters that are set for the TCP socket when it is created
3. Details of the network configuration (e.g., whether the machine is multi-homed, which exact IP address mask was bound to the socket, etc.)

The typical solution to a problem like this is to choose a distinct port, one which you know other applications are not using.

That is why Derby allows the port number to be easily configurable.

Can you use that solution for your situation?

Comment: Thank for the reply. I already applied a distinct port in my application. But I wonder why the derby didnt give error that makes me not to waste time.

Comment: You didn't say what operating system you are on. Some operating systems allow multiple servers to accept requests on the same port, and deliver connections to those servers randomly, or via a round-robin process. This is very useful for, e.g., web servers that want to provide a load-balancing feature. It isn't necessarily useful for Derby, as you've noticed, but the decision is somewhat out of Derby's hands (though you could log an enhancement request at the Derby website to try to improve this)

Comment: My operating system is a windows 7. And Even if I give drba system variable for allowing other clients to connect, clients can not connect some cases, because the connect is refused. But I check the port is listening. So I think I have to give up the embedded mode of derby.